# Database design for user and top 25 recommendations

Tags: mysql, database, relational-database

I got a MySQL database and need to store upto 25 recommendations for each of the users (when user visits the site), here is my simple table that holds userid, recommendation and rank for the recommendation:

```
userid | recommendation | rank
  1    |    movie_A     |   1
  1    |    movie_X     |   2
  ...
  10   |    movie_B     |   1
  10   |    movie_A     |   2
  ....
```

I expect about 10M users and that combined with 25 recommendations would result in 250M rows. Is there any other better ways to design a user-recommendation table?

Thanks!

Comment: I don’t know what your criteria is, but instead of having a “rank” of 1-25, you could consider some sort of scoring system and maybe even have the score be based on some count query (perhaps of related movies or something). My idea about scoring is that the numbers wouldn’t have to be 1-25 with no gaps, but instead just sorted descending and grab 25 of them. This would likely be easier to maintain than having to constantly shift the stack around as you insert more. (Needing to insert one in slot 3, so now you have to bump 3+ up one to insert a new 3 is a bit tedious to maintain.)

Comment: Thanks Nate for the input but the recommendations will be computed by a different system and replicated over to MySQL database for serving purposes. So complete refresh is not an issue. I'm more interested in designing a better table given the recos will be served when a user visits the site.

Comment: I would definitely let others chime in, but I would just make 3 tables: users, movies, and recommendations. The recommendations table would be a joining table between movies and users, it has 3 columns — user_id, movie_id, rank. That’s basically what you have in your question. If you have your indices set, you should be able to join to the 25 records for the user quickly. If you find yourself having performance issues, you can start denormalizing, but that becomes a pain to sync. A movie changed its title? Here comes 5M updates!

Comment: Your present system is fine for now. When you hit 10m users, one of two things will happen: either you'll be rich enough to hire professional help, or too rich to care.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

250 million rows isn't unreasonable in a simple table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE UserMovieRecommendations (
  user_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  movie_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  rank TINYINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (user_id, movie_id, rank),
  FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES Users(user_id),
  FOREIGN KEY (movie_id) REFERENCES Movies(movie_id)
);
```

That's 9 bytes per row. so only about 2GB.

```
25 * 10,000,000 * 9 bytes = 2250000000 bytes, or 2.1GB.
```

Perhaps double that to account for indexes and so on. Still not hard to imagine a MySQL server configured to hold the entire data set in RAM. And it's probably not necessary to hold all the data in RAM, since not all 10 million users will be viewing their data at once.

You might never reach 10 million users, but if you do, I expect that you will be using a server with plenty of memory to handle this.

Answer (score 3):

Is your requirement only to retrieve the 25 recommendations and send it to a UI layer for consumption?
if that is the case, the system that computes the recommendations can build a JSON document and update the value against the Userid. MySQL has support for JSON datatype.

This might not be a good approach if you want to perform search queries on the JSON document.